# How to set the working directory to a bind mount

Tags: docker

I have an image in which the binary I run creates files wherever it runs. I want to be able to access these files from the host. I'm trying to achieve this with this command:

```
docker run -v /tmp/mymount:/mymount -w /mymount myimage:mytag mybinary
```

What I imagine this does is:

1. `-v`: Creates a directory inside the container, `/mymount`, that is accessible from the host at `/tmp/mymount`.
2. `-w`: Runs the binary from `/mymount`.

However when I inspect `/tmp/mymount` from the host, the directory is empty. I have verified that the binary does indeed write the files in its current directory as it should, so I can only assume that these flags don't work in the order described.

Is this the case, and if so, what should I do instead? Ideally something more elegant than changing the run command to this:

```
sh -c 'cd /mymount && mybinary'
```

Comment: -w don't set the location of the binary. Only point the shell to some folder at the start

Comment: The `-v` option replaces `/mymount` in the image, whatever its contents may be, with the contents of the `/tmp/mymount` host directory.  Is that what you expect?  Do you have a [mcve] showing how the files are getting written?

Comment: Replacing the files in the host is what I expect and what I want to happen. The problem is what @JRichardsz points out, that `-w` doesn't set the working directory of the binary. So I think the latter solution, where the run command changes the location the binary runs from is the only option.

Comment: Note that a RUN command or ENTRYPOINT of `cd /mymount && mybinary` has an implicit `sh -c`; you only need to add that yourself when you're using a JSON-format command specification in your Dockerfile.

Comment: What if instead to write files in the binary location, you use an env variable to parametrize that location?. So your binary should read that variable and use it as location to write the required files  ` docker run -v /tmp/mymount:/foo/bar -e FILES_LOCATION=/foo/bar myimage:mytag `

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm doing now, but instead of an env var it's just a CLI flag. But I wish it was possible just from how I run the container.